# Merge [tag:voice-typing] with [tag:voice-recognition]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

[voice-typing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-typing) and [voice-recognition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-recognition) seem synonymous. Let's merge them? As a side note, the proper term is speech recognition and not voice recognition (= speaker recognition).